# I want to press a reviews button and show me the reviews for a specific game

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying  to build an an web app with dotnet mvc and I have a GamesController witch creates games and displays them. Each game has a "Reviews" button and if I click it I want to redirect me to Reviews View in witch we have the specific reviews for the specific game we clicked.

GamesController

```
    namespace mvcGames.Controllers
    {

        public class GamesController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
            public GamesController(ApplicationDbContext db)
            {
                _db = db;
             }

             //Dislpay
             public IActionResult Index()
            {
                IEnumerable<GamesViewModel> game = _db.Games;

                return View(game);
            }
            //Create
            public IActionResult Create()
            {

                return View();
            }
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public IActionResult Create(GamesViewModel game)
            {
                _db.Games.Add(game);
                _db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            public IActionResult ReviewsId(int gameId)
            {
            return RedirectToAction("Reviews", "Reviews", new { gameId = gameId });
            }

        }
    }
```

ReviewsController

```
    namespace mvcGames.Controllers
    {


        public class ReviewsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

            public ReviewsController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Reviews(int GameId)
        {
            var game = _db.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == GameId);
            if (game == null)
                return NotFound();

            var reviews = _db.Reviews.Where(g => g.gameId == GameId).ToList();
            var viewModel=new ReviewsGameModel{
                GamesViewModel=game,
                Reviews=reviews
                
            };
            if (reviews == null || reviews.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();

            return View(viewModel);
        }

        



    }
}


namespace mvcGames.Controllers
{


    public class ReviewsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

        public ReviewsController(ApplicationDbContext db)
        {
            _db = db;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Reviews(int GameId)
        {
            var game = _db.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == GameId);
            if (game == null)
                return NotFound();

            var reviews = _db.Reviews.Where(g => g.gameId == GameId).ToList();
            var viewModel=new ReviewsGameModel{
                GamesViewModel=game,
                Reviews=reviews
                
            };
            if (reviews == null || reviews.Count == 0)
                return NotFound();

            return View(viewModel);
        }

    }
}



    namespace mvcGames.Controllers
    {


        public class ReviewsController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

            public ReviewsController(ApplicationDbContext db)
            {
                _db = db;
            }

            public IActionResult Index()
            {
                return View();
            }

                 public IActionResult Reviews(int GameId)
                 {
                 var game = _db.Games.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Id == GameId);
                 if (game == null)
                    return NotFound();

                var reviews = _db.Reviews.Where(g => g.gameId == GameId).ToList();
                var viewModel=new ReviewsGameModel{
                    GamesViewModel=game,
                    Reviews=reviews
                
                };
                if (reviews == null || reviews.Count == 0)
                    return NotFound();

                return View(viewModel);
            }

         }
    }
```

Models

```
    namespace mvcGames.Models
    {
        public class ReviewsGameModel
        {
            [Key]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            [Range(1,5)]
            public int   Stars { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string? userName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string?  Comment { get; set; }

            [ForeignKey("GamesViewModel")]
            public int gameId { get; set; }

            public List<ReviewsGameModel> Reviews { get; set; }

            public GamesViewModel GamesViewModel { get; set; }


        }
    }
```

```
And the models if it helps.
```

```
    @model IEnumerable<mvcGames.Models.GamesViewModel>


    @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Games";
    }

    <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>



    - 
    @foreach (var game in Model){

        <div class="game-info "  >@game.Title </div>
         <div class="reviewsBtn  ">

         <form asp-controller="Games" asp-action="Reviews" asp-route-gameId="@game.Id" > 
            <button type="submit">Reviews</button>
         </form>

    </div>
        <div class=" mb-3">@game.Description</div>
   
    }
```

This is the Index View of the game.

I tried it like this and it didn't work,I have a 404 error so I guess one of the problems is that there is no Data,so when I try to pass an Id it is null,but I don't know for sure.

I want to know what I should do to make it work,or some tips to make it better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your address(Action) in the index.cshtml of  GamesController  incorrect, you should change it as follows

```
<form asp-controller="Games" asp-action="ReviewsId" asp-route-gameId="@game.Id">
   <button type="submit">Reviews</button>
</form>
```

Because you did not write a special code in the action(ReviewsId of GamesController) and redirect you directly(action Reviews to Reviewscontroller), it is better to redirect directly to its Reviewscontroller

```
  <form asp-controller="Reviews" asp-action="Reviews" asp-route-gameId="@game.Id">
            <button type="submit">Reviews</button>
 </form>
```